# Keyboard shortcuts using Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I have tried using actions class but still not working

1. ```
    Actions action=new Actions(getDriver());
    String ctrlY=Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"y");
    action.sendKeys(ctrlY);
   ```
2. ```
    Actions action=new Actions(getDriver());
    action.keyDown(Keys.ALT).sendKeys("z").keyUp(Keys.ALT).perform();
   ```

above two ways are not working for undo/redo actions

Answer (score -1):

If the sendKeys() method of Selenium isn't working for you I suggest you try the Robot framework for using keyboard shortcuts.

You can do something like;

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
Thread.sleep(1000);
robot.delay(3000);


robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Y);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_Y);
```

I guess this would help sort your problem.